# UDP IP Spoofing

Tags: networking, ip, iptables, udp, spoofing

I have a Ubuntu VPS in Singapore region and I have players who are going to play in my Indian Tournament.

My Indian server accepts only Indian traffic to protect from DDoS.

My players want to play from different location.

So is it possible that Players get connected to Singapore VPS and then

VPS's IP is spoofed to some Indian IP and they can play on my server ?

Server is hosted on UDP port 27000

Here latency doesn't matter.

How do I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Meanwhile we also need to change the IP of player to some fake Indian IP so , that IP will be allowed since Singapore IP is not allowed

No, that won't work. If you spoof the source IP address in outgoing packets, you won't be able to receive any *replies* back – they'll just go to the real owner of that address instead.

Comment: Oh I understood that. Okay that won't work. So for now I just want to know how do I spoof source IP to send it to my Indian server ?

Answer (score 0):

SSH supports TCP tunneling, and many people have used NetCat (`nc`) or `socat` to create UDP-to-TCP forwarders at each end of an SSH TCP tunnel to achieve what you seem to be asking for.

Here's one writeup of how to do it: https://www.qcnetwork.com/vince/doc/divers/udp_over_ssh_tunnel.html

You can find others if you search for "ssh udp forwarding" or "ssh udp tunnel".

Comment: Is it possible to spoof source IP with  iptables ? Thanks!

Comment: Due to the fact that VPS is from Singapore and players will be connecting to VPS first and then VPS will forward traffic to Indian machine. Meanwhile we also need to change the IP of player to some fake Indian IP so , that IP will be allowed since Singapore IP is not allowed.